# How to know the version of Thunderbird Mail in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade, versions

I had a problem with logging in the Thunderbird Mail on my PC that has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I checked in the internet about this issue and got to know that the Thunderbird Mail version must be 38 or higher to support Gmail. So, I want to know how to check the Thunderbird Mail version. I would also like to get different options.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I would also like to get different options*?" Options for what?

Comment: @user535733 I meant options for commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC2Xr.png) Help -> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC2Xr.png) About Thunderbird -> [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC2Xr.png) Version No.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One easy way: http://packages.ubuntu.com

> **Package thunderbird**
>   bionic-updates (mail): Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
>   1:**68.4.1**+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x

Another easy way: The `rmadison` command (included with the `devscripts` package)

```
 $ rmadison thunderbird | grep bionic-updates
  thunderbird | 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 | bionic-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check available and installed version with *apt*:

```
apt-cache policy thunderbird
```

Or if you want to see complete information and what it depends on:

```
apt show thunderbird
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joker said: `apt show thunderbird` is probably what you are looking for
`dpkg -s <packagename>` is an alternative